# what service creates windows security auditing event 4798 in Win 10

Tags: windows-10, process

Using Win 10
At the beginning of every session or working in any app that accesses network, I am getting a flurry of 
"Audit Success - Microsoft Windows Auditing 4798 User Account Management"

This interrupts other work.
The event is marked by a tone and the cursor freezes for an instant. If I am working in Photoshop or LR, whatever I am doing is halted for an instant or even terminated. 
For example, If I am using the marquee tool to grab a partial screen clip in PS or snagit to grab a section of the screen, that 'grab' is stopped.

IT is mostly just annoying as hell and interrupts me editing.

I am the only user on the network.
Can I turn this off to stop the annoyances without hurting anything - and how?

TIA, for any help.

[image]

Comment: So are you running `Windows XP` or `Windows 10`?  Random tags don't help get quality answers.

Comment: *This interrupts other work*...please explain how these events create an interruption. Because even a terribly under-powered computer could log *thousands* of these events per minute without consuming enough system resources to negatively impact a user's experience, this question seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). Please help us understand what exactly is not working properly.

Comment: Sorry.
Win 10
The event is marked by a tone and the cursor freezes for an instant.
If I am working in Photoshop, whatever I am doing is interrupted,

Comment: If what you describe is happening then you have software unique to your configuration causing the event to happen.  What logs the event is causing the behavior to happen, the event logging, isn’t your actual problem.  To be clear even if you were to disable event logging the behavior you describe would continue to happen you just wouldn’t be logging the event.

Comment: Error is linked to COM errors: http://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtPages/EventId_4798_Microsoft-Windows-Complus_62581.asp